# Can i write an if/else condition for a menu effect based on HTML class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a megamneu with the following jQuery. The current menu effect is 'hover-slide' , i would like to change the hover-slide effect to click-slide when a mobile or tablet is found. I have html.mobile and html.tablet located in my HTML head. How would i write that condition based on my html class

I'd like a condition that states , if html.mobile or html.tablet , then menu-effect to 'clide-slide' , else menu effect 'hover-slide'

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.megamenu').megaMenuReloaded({
        menu_speed_show : 300, // Time (in milliseconds) to show a drop down
        menu_speed_hide : 0, // Time (in milliseconds) to hide a drop down
        menu_speed_delay : 100, // Time (in milliseconds) before showing a drop down
        menu_effect : 'hover_slide', // Drop down effect, choose between 'hover_fade', 'hover_slide', 'click_fade', 'click_slide', 'open_close_fade', 'open_close_slide'
        menu_easing : 'jswing', // Easing Effect : 'easeInQuad', 'easeInElastic', etc.
        menu_click_outside : 1, // Clicks outside the drop down close it (1 = true, 0 = false)
        menu_show_onload : 0, // Drop down to show on page load (type the number of the drop down, 0 for none)
        menubar_trigger : 0, // Show the menu trigger (button to show / hide the menu bar), only for the fixed version of the menu (1 = show, 0 = hide)
        menubar_hide : 0, // Hides the menu bar on load (1 = hide, 0 = show)
        menu_responsive : 1, // Enables mobile-specific script
        menu_carousel : 0, // Enable / disable carousel
        menu_carousel_groups : 0 // Number of groups of elements in the carousel
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the conditional (aka "ternary") operator.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.megamenu').megaMenuReloaded({
        menu_speed_show : 300, // Time (in milliseconds) to show a drop down
        menu_speed_hide : 0, // Time (in milliseconds) to hide a drop down
        menu_speed_delay : 100, // Time (in milliseconds) before showing a drop down
        menu_effect : $("html.mobile, html.tablet").length ? 'click_slide' : 'hover_slide', // Drop down effect, choose between 'hover_fade', 'hover_slide', 'click_fade', 'click_slide', 'open_close_fade', 'open_close_slide'
        menu_easing : 'jswing', // Easing Effect : 'easeInQuad', 'easeInElastic', etc.
        menu_click_outside : 1, // Clicks outside the drop down close it (1 = true, 0 = false)
        menu_show_onload : 0, // Drop down to show on page load (type the number of the drop down, 0 for none)
        menubar_trigger : 0, // Show the menu trigger (button to show / hide the menu bar), only for the fixed version of the menu (1 = show, 0 = hide)
        menubar_hide : 0, // Hides the menu bar on load (1 = hide, 0 = show)
        menu_responsive : 1, // Enables mobile-specific script
        menu_carousel : 0, // Enable / disable carousel
        menu_carousel_groups : 0 // Number of groups of elements in the carousel
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like so:

```
if($(body).width() < 768)) {
$('.megamenu').megaMenuReloaded({
    clide-slide : 'hover_slide', // Drop down effect, choose between 'hover_fade'
});
```

Where the 768 is the width of the tablet. The same can be done for the phone.